# Not able to fetch videos on IIS server

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am deploying my Codeigniter project on IIS server. I have kept my images and videos in assets folder. I am able to fetch images but not videos, I am getting error message **The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable** while fetching videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default IIS blocks file extensions that aren't defined in MIME types. This presents with the error your getting.

Add a MIME type for the file extension you have used on your video files, and you should be able to fetch them.